# cannot initialize the type jsonobject

Tags: json

This is my code. I am getting an error at this line `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());` which I am not able to solve, could some one tell if I have made any mistake. This is the error I am getting at this line 'cannot initialize the type jsonobject'.

```
public class Findrss {

    public static <JSONObject> void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?"
        + "v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blog&userip=INSERT-USER-IP");
        java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        String ref = "google.com";

        connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", ref);

        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an IDE or just notepad? Your code throws three exceptions: `MalformedURLException`, `IOException` and `JSONException`. Use a `try-catch` to fix it.

Comment: I am using eclipse to do this

Comment: Are you serious? That is java basics. Eclipse can do it for you.

Comment: Also, second problem: Remove `<JSONObject>` from `public static <JSONObject> void main(String[] args)`. Main method is just `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: If I remove that I will get other error at the same line 'JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type' because of this I have added that.

Comment: I know where to use try catch, but I am confused with this json

Comment: You are confused with Java basics. That's all. All you need is to import the `JSONObject class` (ie: `import org.json.JSONObject;`) from a JSON for Java library (I used `json-20131018`). Your code works perfect. The `<JSONObject>` and the uncovered exceptions are the problem.